# How to cache bson ObjectId

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, caching, redis

I have a question regarding ObjectId caching.

I am caching mongoDB document using redis, and when I check the cached value, only the timeStamp and date of the ObjectId are cached as shown below, and they are being retrieved with values different from the ObjectId of the actual document.

```
"id":{
  "@class":"org.bson.types.ObjectId",
  "timestamp":1658025133,
  "date":["java.util.Date",1658025133000]
},
```

Actual ObjectId: `6311ba39c31566544746d31b`

ObjectId retrieved as cached result: `6311ba3911d1d82cb7892c73`

How can I cache it so that it is fetched as an actual ObjectId value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add custom serializer to serialize ObjectId into String

```
@JsonComponent
class ObjectIdSerializer : StdSerializer<ObjectId>(ObjectId::class.java) {
  override fun serialize(value: ObjectId, gen: JsonGenerator, provider: SerializerProvider) {
    return gen.writeString(value.toString())
  }
}
```

Then

```
objectMapper().registerModule(SimpleModule().addSerializer(ObjectIdSerializer()))
```